# Integrating tracking code into Magento success page

Tags: magento-1.9, checkout, magento-community, ecommerce-tracking

I am looking to integrate a tracking code onto the Magento checkout success page from a company called Paid On Results.

I've been trying to make the snippet of code from the following two pages: http://www.paidonresults.com/integration/advance-tracking.html

And: http://www.magebuzz.com/blog/implement-paidonresults-affiliate-tracking-code-for-magento/

I see that I add the code from the second page so that I can then put the information into the URL in the following bit of code:

```
<script language=JavaScript src="https://secure.paidonresults.net/create-sale?client=java&MerchantID=000&SaleID=Your-Sale-ID&Purchases=Your-Purchases"></script>
<noscript><img src="https://secure.paidonresults.net/create-sale?client=img&MerchantID=000&SaleID=Your-Sale-ID&Purchases=Your-Purchases" width="10" height="10" border="0"></noscript>
```

So I know the merchant ID but as for the Sale ID and Purchases I'm not sure how to get these into the URL.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: page is located at app/design/frontent/YOUR PACKAGE/YOUR TEMPLATE/tamplate/checkout/success.phtml....getOrder id from $this->getOrderId()....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit the `success.phtml` template and add the code from the blog post above (in `<?php ?>` tags), to insert the required variables use:

```
<script language="javascript" src="https://secure.paidonresults.net/create-sale?client=java&MerchantID=000&SaleID=<?php echo $order->getIncrementId() ?>&Purchases=<?php echo $purchases ?>"></script>
```

Also it's not really required to load the product you can use `$item->getPrice()` and `$item->getSku()` where needed

Comment: @Alexander nice to hear that and glad I've helped

Comment: Anyone guide me how can i integrate Custom Feedback Form Code Into Magento -  https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/244255/57334