# How to get Sidebar slider Feedback Form in Home Page?

Tags: magento-1.9, custom-options

I have created Feedback form with PHP,HTML,CSS,JS.

Form Lookalike,

[image]

my feedback form Code

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/32zqgejubfllz0h/AACkB_iIh-KJQxtEUikZ8i9Na?dl=0

how can i apply Sidebar Sliding into my home page and all other pages?

Comment: You want to display that green box in all Magento pages ?

Comment: Yes, I need to display in all pages including home page.

Comment: See my answer bellow

Answer (score 2):

1. > app/design/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/layout/local.xml

   ```
   //add this:
   <default>
       <reference name="content">
           <block type="core/template" name="feedback.box" template="html/feedbackbox.phtml"/>
       </reference>
   </default>
   ```
2. > app/design/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/template/html/feedbackbox.phtml

   ```
   //Your feedback code goes here.
   ```

Now your feedback will be displayed in all Magento content pages.

#### UPDATE:

You should not add `<head>`, `<html>`and `<body>` etc... tags in your phtml, the scripts head you add them in `local.xml`

> app/design/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/template/html/feedbackbox.phtml

```
<!--Feedback Form HTML START -->
    <div id="mrova-feedback">
        <div id="mrova-contact-thankyou" style="display: none;">
            Thank you.  We'hv received your feedback.
        </div>
        <div id="mrova-form">
            <form id="mrova-contactform" action="feedbackbox.phtml" method="post">
                <ul >
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-name">Your Name*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-name" class="required" id="mrova-name" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-email">Email*</label> <input type="text" name="mrova-email" class="required" id="mrova-email" value="">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label for="mrova-message">Message*</label>
                        <textarea class="required" id="mrova-message" name="mrova-message"  rows="8" cols="30"></textarea>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <input type="submit" value="Send" id="mrova-sendbutton" name="mrova-sendbutton">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div id="mrova-img-control"></div>
    </div>
<!-- Feedback Form HTML END --> 

<?php
header('content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8');

if (isset($_GET["mrova-name"])) {
    $name = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-name']);
    $email = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-email']);
    $message = strip_tags($_GET['mrova-message']);
    $header = "From: ". $name . " <" . $email . ">rn"; 

    $ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
    $httpref = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
    $httpagent = $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'];
    $today = date("F j, Y, g:i a");    

    $recipient = 'abc@gmail.com';
    $subject = 'Contact Form';
    $mailbody = "
First Name: $name
Email: $email
Message: $message

IP: $ip
Browser info: $httpagent
Referral: $httpref
Sent: $today
";
    $result = 'success';

    if (mail($recipient, $subject, $mailbody, $header)) {
        echo json_encode($result);
    }
}
?>
```

> app/design/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/layout/local.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <default>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_css</type><name>css/mrova-feedback-form.css</name></action>
            <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/mrova-feedback-form.js</name></action>
        </reference>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="core/template" name="feedback.box" template="html/feedbackbox.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Now you add your css, js content inside these files in :

> skin/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/css/mrova-feedback-form.css
>
> skin/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/js/mrova-feedback-form.js

Comment: How to create phtml file using with HTML and PHP code?

Comment: Yes, you can put php and html in phtml, But if you mean controller, model, etc... you need to create them So create a module for that.

Comment: In my case there is no controller and model, just want to display feedback form in all pages.

Comment: So, Yes you can put your php and html without problem, `PHTML = PHP+HTML` :)

Comment: @PRINCE  step 1) https://snag.gy/UKiLxH.jpg code : https://justpaste.it/6df9c step 2) https://snag.gy/JC7sBe.jpg code : https://codeshare.io/2K7EBN after clear cache and reindexed still not working. can i get help?p?

Comment: @PRINCE FYI - My Magento version 1.9.2.3

Comment: Share me please all the `local.xml` and there is an issue in your phtml content, I will update my answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84115/discussion-between-zus-and-prince).

Comment: @PRINCE join chat,, i am shared code

Comment: @PRINCE I have updated, can you check?

Comment: @PRINCE Just want to confirm, in our workout where is add our jquery?http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js

Comment: The jQuery is added in your theme in xml

Comment: Please accept the answer if it solved your problem

Comment: @PЯINCƏ There is no file called local.xml in app/design/frontend/yourTheme/themeName/layout/local.xml, manual edit require?

Comment: @Gem you have replaced `/yourTheme/themeName` with your theme information right ? you have not to put exactly `/yourTheme/themeName`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ I understand, app/design/frontend/default/mogo/layout/local.xml.

Comment: After i configured everything sidebar issue, design like https://snipboard.io/z8QePX.jpg

Comment: and click event also not working, could you pls help me to find out the error?

Comment: @Gem cool, so if you haven't this file `local.xml`, you have to create it

Comment: @PЯINCƏ  am done with all files, finally display side bar alignment error,

Comment: If i click sidebar nothing will happen.

Comment: fyi https://snipboard.io/KgEbtv.jpg

Comment: Try to add this : `jQuery('#mrova-img-control').click(function() {alert('My click work')});`

Comment: @PЯINCƏ any help https://magento.stackexchange.com/q/297791/57334

Comment: Can we put that local.xml in module ?