# Attribute Set Save button Error : Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'strip' of null

Tags: magento-1.9, error, attribute-set

If i try to click save attribute set button, i am getting error like,

[image]

How can i solve the error?

Comment: Are you using any third party extension or did you write your any custom code ?

Comment: yes, i am develop feedback-form custom module...

Comment: my feedbackform : https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/245298/57334

Comment: @SourabhKumarSharma How can i prevent my new module collapse to  existing module?

Comment: The object associate to strip doesn 't exist. Are you sure you have the object valid?

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/138646)

Comment: could you pls explain in brief? @thomas